# Unable to use dynamic_cast with generics

Tags: generics, c++-cli, dynamic-cast

I have a generic class `Client` which has a single type parameter. The type parameter is any reference type derived from `Base`. So I declare the class as below:

```
generic <class T>
where T : Base, gcnew()
public ref class Client {
  T val;
  void SetVal(Base ^bval){

    val = dynamic_cast<T>(bval);  // error C2682: cannot use 'dynamic_cast' to convert from 'Base ^' to 'T'

  }  
};
```

Why do I get a compile error when using `dynamic_cast` to convert from `Base` to one of its derived classes? I was expecting the cast to compile but fail at runtime (by returning `nullptr`) in case the argument was of incorrect type.

Answer (score 4):

Try `dynamic_cast <T^>`.

Pointers have to be cast to other pointers, handles to other handles, and so forth.

Comment: that is what I thought would work. Even docs say "The syntax used within the body of the generic should be T^ and '->' instead of '.'." (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/skef48fy.aspx) But in reality, even the simplest example where the type parameter is used with '^' gives the error: "error C3229: 'T ^' : indirections on a generic type parameter are not allowed"

Comment: @Agnel: The other thing I remember is that having a derivation-from-reference-class constraint does not automatically add a is-a-reference-class constraint.  Try adding `T : ref class`.

Comment: Thanks. This looks like an abandoned compiler bug http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/761208/unable-to-use-generic-parameter-as-argument-for-dynamic-cast-in-c-cli

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`safe_cast<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/extensions/safe-cast-cpp-component-extensions) which throws an `InvalidCastException` instead of returning `nullptr`.

Catch the exception and return the default:

```cpp
ref class Cast
{
public:
 generic <class T>
 static T Dynamic(System::Object^ value)
 {
  try
  {
   return safe_cast<T>(value);
  }
  catch (System::InvalidCastException^)
  {
   return T();
  }
 };
};
```

```cpp
val = Cast::Dynamic<T>(bval);
```